# Find number(s) repeated k times in unsorted array

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

We have array that contain integer number, I would like to find the numbers that repeated k time in this array. The array is not sorted, and the numbers are not bounded.

Example,

A(20, 6, 99, 3, 6, 2, 1,11,41, 31, 99, 6, 7, 8, 99, 10, 99, ,6)

Find the numbers repeated more than 3 times.

Answer: 6,99

possible answer using bit wise operations (xor) or combination? Efficiency in running time Big(o) is required as well as the space capacity.

This is not homework, its simply interesting problem.

Comment: Is O(n) time & space "efficient"? What about O(n lg n) time and O(1) space? Trivial algorithms come to mind for both. Often, the perfect is the enemy of the good. Better have a good easy method, than an optimal but unintelligible one.

Comment: I have not come across such a problem in my research, so I can not tell if N lg N efficient or not. but for sure O(1) in space its. what is your approach to the problem in order to get n lg n?

Comment: Sort the array using an in-place O(n lg n) sort, then look for a run of k or more of some element? All you'd need is to run through the sorted array with a counter; if you get to three, print out what you're looking at; if what you're looking at changes, reset the counter to 1.

Comment: Correction: the counter should get to k, not three... :)

Comment: Since they're integers, they can be sorted in better than O(n log n) time. For example, bucket sort and radix sort are good for fixed length integers, and there are algorithms to sort variable-length integers in O(n log log n).

Answer (score 0):

Patrick87 probably has the most straightforward answer in the comments, so I'll give another approach.

As you iterate over your list, you will both create and insert into a map an element (id, value), where id is equivalent to the number, and the value matched a count initialized to 1 upon insertion. If the value is already present in the map, you just increment the counter.

Insertions into your map will take O(log k) time where k is the size of the map. Your total map creation time is therefore O(n log n).

After the map is created, you can iterate over it, and output any number whose count == target count.

Time complexity = O(n) + O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n)
Space complexity = O(n) + O(n) = O(n)

If you're looking for better space complexity, you're not going to get it... Even if the numbers are read from a stream, you need to track individual values which is O(n).

Comment: using a hashmap (`unordered_map`) would make the complexity O(n). right?

Comment: @SudhanshuVishnoi: In the average case. Depending on what OP means by Big-O, a hash table could be a bad choice because worst case is O(n^2). A binary search tree has guaranteed O (n lg n) complexity. If you perform an integer sort and then a normal walk over the data, then complexity is O(n) guaranteed, but I don't like evaluating integer sorts this way because it depends on the # of bits used for representation.